# analytics.js: Tracking a website which is put in an iframe on another domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, cookies, google-analytics

Let's pretend I have a website that is hosted on `app.com`. My website is published on another website hosted on `platform.com` throught an iframe.

```
<html class="platform.com">
    <body>
         <iframe src="app.com">
              //ga init code
              ga("create", "UA-0000000", {
                   storage: "none",
                   userId: options.userId,
                   clientId: options.userId
              });
         </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I can see requests dispatching to `google-analytics.com/collect`, but no data is actually submitted to Google Analytics reports.

[image]

I have checked Filters in GA Admin, and there are none. I think that the issue is related to the current domain and the request source domain mismatch, but I can't figure out what I can actually do to solve this.

As you understand, I have no access to the `platform.com` code, all I can manipulate is the code inside iframe.

I used these sources:

[About GA cross-domain tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain)

[About GA cookies](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have control over the parent you cannot track interactions in the parent (you'd need to implement the postmessage interface and that would require you to insert a function into platform.com).

However there should be no problem with tracking interactions within the iframe itself (*n.b.* I trust that the GA code is actually within the source code of the framed page, not literally pasted between the iframe tags).

It does not make sense to use both the cookieDomain.auto and the storage:none setting since these are mutually exclusive (cookieDomain:auto tells the ga object to use the current "main" domain as cookie domain, storage:none tells ga not to use storage like cookies; in any case you are sending your own client id and you do not need cookies).

I suggest to use the ga debugger extension (available at least for chrome) and also to check your account for filters. Usually GA refuses to send anything if there is an error, so the problem might be very well at the receiving end.

Comment: Yes, I just want to track interactions inside iframe. I have removed the cookieDomain parameter but effect is the same. I have checked the GA Admin panel for filters and there are none. There are no errors in the console and the requests are dispatched without any problems, but I'll check the debugger extension anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Just to rule out the trivial, you did check the realtime reports or waited a few hours before you checked (there is a  delay due to processing time) ?

Comment: I am checking realtime reports for a certain event. When I open my website directly (without iframe), the event appears in the reports. But when i open it through `platform.com` iframe, nothing appears in reports.

Comment: I have checked the GA debugger logs, they seem to be almost identical, except for `referrer` and `location` fields. No errors :(

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#disabling_cookies

It looks like you should generate the `clientId` on the parent, send it via `postMessage` to the iframe, and in the iframe you have to add: `'storage': 'none'`,

So it will look like this:

```js
var clientId = 'RECEIVED_FROM_PARENT' ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-YY', 'auto', {
    'storage': 'none',
    'clientId': clientId
});
```